# .net core different error handling for API and Web Page controllers

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm trying to setup exception handling in a new .net Core 2.2 Web application project.

Currently I tried two approaches - being

1. Use the built-in ExceptionHandlers: `app.UseExceptionHandler`, `app.UseStatusCodePages`, etc...
2. Created my own middleware to handle exceptions which I've added to the bottom of this question.

Now, the main issue is that I can use my own custom middleware, but (of course) this is used on *all* requests, and not only on API calls.

What I would like to achieve is have separated exception logic for Web API and Web Pages, so that I can use my custom middleware and return format for API, and use `app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage()` for example for web pages.

### Exception middleware for reference:

```
public static class ExceptionMiddleware
{
    public static void ConfigureExceptionHandler(this IApplicationBuilder app, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory,
        bool includeStackTrace = false)
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler(builder =>
            builder.Run(async context =>
            {
                var logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger(nameof(ExceptionMiddleware));

                // Set the response status code
                context.Response.StatusCode = (int) HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
                context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";

                var contextFeature = context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();
                if (contextFeature != null)
                {
                    // Get the current exception
                    var currentException = contextFeature.Error;
                    logger.LogError(currentException, $"Something went wrong: {currentException}");

                    ErrorDetails errorDetails;

                    if (includeStackTrace)
                        errorDetails = new ExtendedErrorDetails
                        {
                            StatusCode = (HttpStatusCode) context.Response.StatusCode,
                            Message = currentException.Message,
                            StackTrace = currentException.StackTrace
                        };
                    else
                        errorDetails = new ErrorDetails
                        {
                            StatusCode = (HttpStatusCode) context.Response.StatusCode,
                            Message = "Internal Server Error."
                        };

                    // Write the response
                    await context.Response.WriteAsync(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(errorDetails));
                }
            }));
    }

    private class ErrorDetails
    {
        public HttpStatusCode StatusCode { [UsedImplicitly] get; set; }

        public string Message { [UsedImplicitly] get; set; }
    }

    private class ExtendedErrorDetails : ErrorDetails
    {
        public string StackTrace { [UsedImplicitly] get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could not identify the error from exception, I suggest you try to make different route for mvc and web api. For web api, add attribute route with `api`, and then check the request path in the middleware or exception handler like

```
    app.UseExceptionHandler(builder =>
    {
            builder.Run(async context =>
            {
                    context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;                   
                    var error = context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>() as ExceptionHandlerFeature;
                    var requestPath = error.Path;                    
            });
    });
```

Update:

```
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

        app.UseWhen(context => context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api"), subApp =>
        {
            subApp.UseExceptionHandler(builder =>
            {
                builder.Run(async context =>
                {
                    context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
                    await context.Response.WriteAsync("Error");
                });
            });
        });
```

Comment: I tried checking the path, with context.Request.GetEncodedUrl(), but I couldn't figure out how to use `UseDeveloperExceptionPage` when it's not an API call.

Comment: @Nsevens You could configure the excetionhandler for api with `UseWhen`. Check the update.